# Регулярное выражение для пароля (английские буквы, цифры и спец. символы)

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, веб-программирование

`` ^([A-Za-z0-9~`'\&quot;!@#№\?\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+\\=<>\|\/\.,:;\[\]{}]{6,25})$ ``

Регулярное выражение для атрибута pattern, поэтому двойные кавычки заменил на &quot;
По какой-то причине это регулярное выражение пропускает русские буквы.

Полный код поля:
`` <input id="registration-form-password" name="password" class="form-control form-control" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" minlength="6" maxlength="25" pattern="^([A-Za-z0-9~`'\&quot;!@#№\?\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+\\=<>\|\/\.,:;\[\]{}]{6,25})$" required data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Пароль должен содержать минимум 6 символов: английские буквы, цифры и символы ~ ` ' &quot; ! @ # № ? $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = &lt; &gt; \ | / . , : ; [ ] { }"> ``

Попробовал регулярку закинуть на https://regex101.com/
Там все работает правильно.

Если проверять регуляркой через js, скорее всего будет все работать, но мне желательно через атрибут pattern. У меня на нем построена валидация.

Comment: Если есть возможность, уговорите заказчика не валидировать пароль регуляркой) Что плохого в русских буквах в пароле? maxlength=25 я бы убрал)

Comment: надеюсь, атрибут pattern это не единственная вещь, из которой состоит ваша валидация.

Comment: @teran, если некто захочет обойти эту валидацию при регистрации, скорее всего он выберет себе нормальный пароль)

Comment: ваш `&quot;` в данном случае бесполезная замена. как и экранирования.

Comment: @teran Конечно нет. Учитывается еще сложность пароля и валидация на сервере

Comment: @vp_arth Просто руглярка неправильная, скорее всего из-за того, что она находится внутри кавычек. Если русские буквы пропускает, может пропускать и еще какие-то символы не из списка.

Comment: Белый список символов пароля - плохая практика. Должны быть разрешены любые символы, хоть иероглифы. Вам же их в базе не хранить)

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать вопрос вставив исполняемый фрагмент кода где воспроизводится проблема. При редактировании в панели инструментов значок `<>`

Comment: Придумывать какие-то правила для пароля имеет смысл разве что с точки зрения, чтобы заставить пользователя использовать довольно сложный пароль. Но поскольку тут пароль `123456` вполне удовлетворяет, то смысл всего действа что-то не ясен.

Answer (score 4):

не надо в квадратных скобках ничего экранировать кроме как самих слеша и квадртных скобок. для кавычки используйте hex-нотацию `\x22`. Минус пишите в самом конце, т.к. используется для указания диапазонов. внешние скобки тоже ни к чему. Некоторые классы символов, можно сократить, например, `a-zA-Z0-9_` до `\w`

```html
<input id  name="password" class="form-control form-control" 
type="text" 
placeholder="Пароль" 
minlength="6"
maxlength="25" 
pattern="^[\w~'`!@#№?$%^&*()=+<>|/\\.,:;\[\]{} \x22-]{6,25}$" required >
```

ну и повторюсь,  нет смысла в подобных ограничениях. Сложность пароля они не валидируют никак, а лишь ограничивают пользователя. На бэкенде вы все равно храните хэш, поэтому без разницы что там вообще внутри.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Поставлю только ограничение от 6 до 50 символов, буду показывать сложность пароля для того, чтобы пользователь понимал насколько безопасен его пароль

Comment: @ВладиславНиков не забывайте ставить галки слева от ответов, которые решили ваши вопросы